# Problems using Flask on a shared hosting server

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, flask, fastcgi

I'm trying to deploy a Flask application on a BlueHost shared hosting server. I have been following [this guide](https://willhaley.com/blog/flask-on-bluehost/). I have made one change, and that is in the `.fcgi` file. I'm not using `flup`. This is my `.fcgi` file (`flask.fcgi`):

```
#!/path/to/venv/bin/python
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from server import app

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

I've made the file executable, and when I run `./flask.fcgi` from the command line (via SSH) it returns the HTML page for the index route, which is what I expect. But if I navigate to `mydomain.com/flask.fcgi` I receive a 500 Internal Server error. Checking the server logs I can see this message:

```
/path/to/venv/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I encountered this error before while installing `openssl` and rectified it by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to include the path to the location where the libraries were installed. This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
# For Flask
PassEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH
PassEnv REQUEST_METHOD
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi

RewriteEngine On

# For Flask
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=/path/to/public_html/flask.fcgi
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ flask.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteOptions inherit
```

You can see that I try to pass in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, but to no avail, I continue to receive the 500 Internal Server errors, regardless of whether I navigate to `mydomain.com/page` or to `mydomain.com/flask.fcgi` directly.

I'm entirely at a loss of where to go from here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what the problem was. I needed to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_RUN_PATH` before compiling `openssl` and `python`. I set the paths and then ran `./Configure` and `make && make install` for `openssl`, and the same for `python`.